# SELECT for a Parent, Children and ORDER BY [Order] column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, parent-child

I have a table `myTable` in SQL Server that looks like this:

| Id | ParentId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 |
| 100 | 3 | 1 |
| 10 | 10 | 1 |
| 194 | 10 | 1 |
| 295 | 194 | 1 |
| 205 | 194 | 2 |
| 215 | 194 | 3 |
| 322 | 10 | 2 |
| 404 | 10 | 3 |
| 435 | 10 | 4 |
| 507 | 10 | 5 |
| 206 | 10 | 6 |
| 330 | 10 | 7 |
| 425 | 10 | 8 |
| 428 | 10 | 9 |
| 488 | 10 | 10 |
| 432 | 10 | 11 |
| 633 | 10 | 12 |

I want my stored procedure to return an output for a given `ParentId` with all it's `Id`s and their children sorted by `Order`.

Examples of the desired result for the table above:

Test `ParentId` = 1 should return:

| Id | ParentId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |

Test `ParentId` = 4 should return -- *Testing that even when a `Id` is not a `ParentId` of it self the lineage in correct order is produced*

| Id | ParentId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 |

Test `ParentId` = 2 should return:

| Id | ParentId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 |

Test `ParentId` = 3 should return:

| Id | ParentId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 100 | 3 | 1 |

Test `ParentId` = 10 should return (this is the tricky one):

| Id | ParentId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 1 |
| 194 | 10 | 1 |
| 295 | 194 | 1 |
| 205 | 194 | 2 |
| 215 | 194 | 3 |
| 322 | 10 | 2 |
| 404 | 10 | 3 |
| 435 | 10 | 4 |
| 507 | 10 | 5 |
| 206 | 10 | 6 |
| 330 | 10 | 7 |
| 425 | 10 | 8 |
| 428 | 10 | 9 |
| 488 | 10 | 10 |
| 432 | 10 | 11 |
| 633 | 10 | 12 |

I have managed to get the `Id`s for a given `ParentId` with the following code and am able to sort the order of the `Id`'s `Id` recursively:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (Id INT, ParentID INT, [Order] INT)

INSERT INTO @myTable 
VALUES
(1,1,1),
(2,2,2),
(3,3,3),
(4,1,2),
(5,1,1),
(6,1,3),
(7,4,1),
(8,2,2),
(9,2,1),
(100,3,1),
(10,10,1),
(194,10,1),
(295,194,1),
(205,194,2),
(322,10,2),
(215,194,3),
(404,10,3),
(435,10,4),
(507,10,5),
(206,10,6),
(330,10,7),
(425,10,8),
(428,10,9),
(488,10,10),
(432,10,11),
(633,10,12)


IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#myTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #myTable
END

SELECT * 
INTO #myTable 
FROM @myTable;

WITH ChildHierarchy AS 
(
    -- Base query: find the direct children of the given ParentId
    SELECT 
        Id, ParentId, [Order], 0 AS HierarchyLevel, 
        CAST([Order] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SortPath
    FROM 
        #myTable
    WHERE 
        ParentId = 1 AND Id != 1

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive query: find the children of each child
    SELECT 
        O.Id, O.ParentId, O.[Order], HierarchyLevel + 1, 
        CAST(ChildHierarchy.SortPath + '.' + CAST(O.[Order] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM 
        #myTable O
    INNER JOIN 
        ChildHierarchy ON O.ParentId = ChildHierarchy.Id
)
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Id, ParentId, [Order], CAST(0 AS varchar) AS HierarchyLevel, 
         CAST(0 AS varchar) AS SortPath 
     FROM 
         #myTable 
     WHERE 
         Id = 1

     UNION
     
     SELECT * 
         FROM ChildHierarchy) AS X
     ORDER BY 
    [Order] ASC, X.SortPath ASC
```

All the test produce the write order except Test `ParentId` = 10 gives:
[image]

There would only ever be one level of hierarchy per row (i.e. no parent's child's child will be on a row in another column) in @myTable

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Please explain - in words -  why filtering for parentid = 4 that you should get id = 6 (which has parentid = 1)  *and* why only 6 is chosen where the parentid = (parentid of id 4).

Comment: It shouldn't. That is a mistake in the example I gave. I have now edited it. Thanks for pointing out 

Comment: Still why is 4 returned before 7 if the `Order` is higher?

Comment: @Charlieface - good point - This is because each lineage gets UNION under the parent after the recursion. My example code was not showing that correctly before as the UNION was the other way round - I just corrected it. It worked in the original example code because Id = 4 was organically in the table before Id = 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not matter what the type of SortPath column is, you can use varbinary instead of varchar. It will help to sort it correctly.

```
DECLARE @root INT
SET @root = 10;

WITH ChildHierarchy AS 
(
    -- Base query: find the direct children of the given ParentId
    SELECT 
        Id, ParentId, [Order], 0 AS HierarchyLevel, 
        CAST([Order] AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS SortPath
    FROM 
        #myTable
    WHERE 
        ParentId = @root AND Id != @root

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive query: find the children of each child
    SELECT 
        O.Id, O.ParentId, O.[Order], HierarchyLevel + 1, 
        ChildHierarchy.SortPath + CAST(o.[Order] AS BINARY(2))
    FROM 
        #myTable O
    INNER JOIN 
        ChildHierarchy ON O.ParentId = ChildHierarchy.Id
)
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM ChildHierarchy
     UNION
     SELECT 
         Id, ParentId, [Order], CAST(0 AS varchar) AS HierarchyLevel, 
         CAST(0 AS VARBINARY) AS SortPath 
     FROM 
         #myTable 
     WHERE 
         Id = @root) AS X
ORDER BY 
   X.[SortPath] ASC
```

The result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: That solved it! Thanks  - [SortPath] was there only for the purposes of this sorting, therefore not essential to be human readable.

Few questions to understand what's happening to better understand the solution:

1. What does CASTING as VARBINARY mean? I can see what it has done; i.e. made the value of [SortPath] such that when sorted, numbers in [SortPath] >9 don't get treated as strings.

2. Why have you casted [Order] as BINARY(2)?

Comment: @shbshk It's basically concatenating them all together, but as a fixed width value (rather than a variable length string) so that it sorts correctly. You might want `binary(4)` if you need numbers above 65535

Comment: For any one who uses this: I just realized that one pre requisite for this to work is that the `Order` of children of the same parent HAS TO ALWAYS be unique. If the `Order` of two children of the same parent are the same e.g. 1, then they won't sort meaningfully.

Comment: @shbshk, in your example it can be BINARY(1) because [ORDER] < 256. So as Charlieface replyed you may need more. Just in case, BINARY(2) is for 32 767. Varbinary just replaces varchar for proper sorting.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `hierarchyid` for this.** `hierarchyid` is designed for this type of tree-shaped table, allowing sorting and querying by a hierarchy.

You begin by doing a regular recursive CTE. Concatenate each recursive `[Order]` value together, separated  by `/`. Then simply cast the final result to `hierarchyid` and sort by it.

```sql
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
      t.Id,
      t.ParentId,
      t.[Order],
      CONCAT('/', CAST([Order] AS varchar(8000)), '/') AS SortPath
    FROM #myTable t
    WHERE t.Id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      t.Id,
      t.ParentId,
      t.[Order],
      CONCAT(cte.SortPath, t.[Order], '/')
    FROM #myTable t
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Id = t.ParentId
      AND t.Id <> t.ParentId  -- remove root
)
SELECT
  Id,
  ParentId,
  [Order],
  SortPathId = CAST(SortPath AS hierarchyid)
FROM cte
ORDER BY 
  SortPathId;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/ugrNbz71)

I must say, your current design is questionable. The root values should not have the `ParentId` being themselves, they should have `NULL` instead. This would remove the requirement for the commented line above.